# Using promises with setTimeout

Tags: asynchronous, promise, reason, bucklescript

I am new to Reason, currently trying to convert a personal project from js to reason. Mostly it has been easy so far apart from async stuff.
I am not able to call my function recursively with delay.
I have a function `getPrice` which returns a promise of int

```
type getPrice = unit => Js.Promise.t(int)
```

I want to make another function `checkPrice`, which checks the current price by given user price endlessly unless condition is met.

```js
let rec checkPrice = (userPrice) =>
  Js.Promise.(
   getPrice()
    |> then_(
     (currentPrice) =>
       if (currentPrice >= userPrice) {
         resolve(currentPrice)
       } else {
         /* call this function with setTimeout */
         checkPrice(userPrice)
       }
   )
);
```

But I am getting type mismatch saying `setTimeout` should be of type unit

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Make a separate helper function that returns a promise for the timeout, then use promise chaining.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Js.Promise` API is unfortunately absolutely terrible, mostly because the JS API is just plain unsound, but it's not very well thought out on the Reason side either. There might be some convenience fixes coming to `Js.Promise`, but hopefully the entire thing is replaced with a proper solution in the not too distant future.

In the here and now, however, you'll have to do something like this:

```js
external toExn : Js.Promise.error => exn = "%identity";

let rec checkPrice = (userPrice) =>
  Js.Promise.(
    getPrice()
    |> then_(
     (currentPrice) =>
       if (currentPrice >= userPrice) {
         resolve(currentPrice)
       } else {
         Js.Promise.make((~resolve, ~reject) =>
           Js.Global.setTimeout(
             fun () =>
               checkPrice(userPrice)
               |> then_((v) => [@bs] resolve(v) |> Js.Promise.resolve)
               |> catch((e) => [@bs] reject(toExn(e)) |> Js.Promise.resolve)
               |> ignore,
             0
           ) |> ignore
         )
       }
   )
);
```

Comment: ahh got it now, Thanks a lot for explaining
Yes async (promises) are the only part cringeworthy right now, rest is an absolute delight
Also wondering,
can the type checker force me to write catch statements for promise ?
Like it gives for non exhaustive pattern matches ?

Comment: It can, and there's even a library wrapping promises that does so: https://github.com/wokalski/vow